# Encoding problems when using GDB $_streq

Tags: python, c++, gdb

I have a variable of type `(char *)`, here is its content:

```
(gdb) p pname
$1 = 0x2aaaadb3d510 "this\256__name__"
```

I got this error while I'm using `$_streq` in GDB:

```
(gdb) p $_streq(pname, "name")
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
Error occurred in Python: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

##### My environments

- GDB version: 12.1
- Python version used by GDB: 2.6.5
- `PYTHONIOENCODING`: UTF-8
- Python setting in ~/.gdbinit

```
python
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
end
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: As a workaround you could try this: `p $_memeq(pname, "name", 5)`

Comment: Hi @ssbssa, thanks for your workaround. It's helpful!